# Entity framework keeps creating multiple records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, model, foreign-keys

I am encountering a problem in this particular method. The first time i save it works by creating a single record in AppointmentEvent and changing the verified variable in Appointment, but it creates the user record again.

```
private void CreateAppointment(Employee user)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new CosmeticContext())
                {
                    Appointment appointment = db.Appointment.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == phoneNumber.name && o.surname == phoneNumber.surname && o.verified == false);
                    appointment.verified = true;
                    PhoneNumber ph = db.PhoneNumber.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == phoneNumber.name && o.surname == phoneNumber.surname);
                    db.PhoneNumber.Remove(ph);
                    db.AppointmentEvent.Add(new AppointmentEvent
                    {
                        date = DateTime.Now,
                        Employees = user,
                        Appointments = appointment,
                        EventComment = EventComment.Save
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
          }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                DbScript.ShowEntityErrors(e);
            }
        }
```

When i run it the second time it duplicates user, appointmentEvent and the Appointment records with the previous values. When i went through the debugger i saw that db.AppointmentEvent.Local has 0 records, but after the second time Add method creates 2 records in db.AppointmentEvent.Local. I dont understand how one Add method can add 2 records. Google was not helpfull in showing the right case for me, but shouldnt the using block dispose everything correctly?

Here are some additional classes that contain objects that are used here:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int employeeId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25), MinLength(4)]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25), MinLength(4)]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(25), MinLength(4)]
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100), MinLength(20)]
    public string password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AppointmentEvent> AppointmentEvents { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentEvent
{
    public int appointmentEventId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Appointment Appointments { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EventComment EventComment { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public int appointmentId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(30)]
    public string surname { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(20), Phone]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AppointmentEvent> AppointmentEvents { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to tell that i am creating a windows forms application and more code, which shows the user part.:
This is Form nr2.:(in which i have the problem with the records)

```
    public partial class CallCenter : Form
    {
        Employee employee;
        static ListTime listTime = new ListTime();
        Button pushedButton = new Button();

        public CallCenter(Employee loginEmployee)
        {

            employee = loginEmployee;

            InitializeComponent();
            tableLayoutPanel2.CellPaint += tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint;
            GeneratedServiceTypeComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceType));
            textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
            RefreshAppointmentAvailabilityTable();
        }

   private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GenerateButton.Enabled = true;
                SaveButton.Enabled = false;
                this.NameBox.Text = string.Empty;
                SurnameBox.Text = string.Empty;
                PhoneBox.Text = string.Empty;
                GeneratedNameBox.Text = string.Empty;
                GeneratedSurnameBox.Text = string.Empty;
                GeneratedPhoneBox.Text = string.Empty;
                pushedButton.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                ChangeAppointmentAvailabilityButtonsStatus(false);
                CreateAppointment(employee);
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            { MessageBox.Show(f.ToString()); }

        }
    ...
    }
```

This is from form1:(Login screen)

```
    private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db = new CosmeticContext())
        {  
            bool verify = false;
            Employee employee = db.Employee.FirstOrDefault(o => o.userName == UserNameBox.Text);
            if (employee == null)
                MessageBox.Show("Sads lietotajs nav atrasts datubaze", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                verify = PasswordAlgorithm.DoesPasswordMatch(employee.password, PasswordBox.Text);
                if (verify)
                    if (employee.EmployeeType == EmployeeType.Seller)
                    {
                        CallCenter form1 = new CallCenter(employee);
                        form1.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is `user` defined in `Employees = user,` block? please show us code!

Comment: since you are fetching the `user` from database, I don't see any problem in your code! waiting to see some elegant answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your user being tracked by the EntityFramework Context?
If it's not tracked EF does not know any better and will gladly make the association but by adding a new User instead of associating the appointment with the existing one. I suspect this is what is happening here:

[ObjectContext.AddObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx) and [ObjectSet.AddObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277.aspx): 
 The AddObject method is for adding newly created objects that do not exist in the database. The entity will get an automatically generated temporary EntityKey and its EntityState will be set to Added. When SaveChanges is called, it will be clear to the EF that this entity needs to be inserted into the database.

[ObjectContext.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) and [ObjectSet.Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487214.aspx): 
 On the other hand, Attach is used for entities that already exist in the database. Rather than setting the EntityState to Added, Attach results in an Unchanged EntityState, which means it has not changed since it was attached to the context. Objects that you are attaching are assumed to exist in the database. If you modify the objects after they’ve been attached, when you call SaveChanges the value of the EntityKey is used to update (or delete) the appropriate row by finding its matching ID in the db table.

Comment: Thanks your solution guided me to an answer.
I putted 
db.Employee.Attach(user);
in the place where im saving and now its working correctly.